# Django / postgres - maintain a table of counters

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I want to maintain a running counter per user, that will be given to the user items.

`User` table will have a `item_counter` column

```
class Item:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_num = models.IntegerField() # should be populated from the user table
```

The question, when the user is creating an item, what is the best way to increment the counter and to copy the new counter to the newly created item, atomically?

Technically I atomically need to:

- Increment and get the counter of the user
- Create a new Item with the value for `item_counter`

What is the django / postgres way to do that?

**EDIT - example:**

**Users table:**

```
| username | item_counter |
| john     |   20         |
```

Now, the user sends `POST /item`. The result will be:
**Items table:**

```
| name   |  item_num |
| my_item |    21     |
```

**Users table:**

```
| username | item_counter |
| john     |   21         |
```

Of course, there can be many users. Each user has an `item_counter` of its own.

Comment: Can you please provide more info, to your question. It is very vague. What do you mean by "what is the best way to increment the counter and to copy the new counter to the newly created item, atomically". The reason I am asking is because I feel like I am missing some details while understanding your question.

Comment: I think it is that simple, I simply want to increment a counter and to use it in another table. I've added an example

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to assign a special integer to your newly created item record whose value will be fetched from a user's counter variable. The user's counter variable will increment every time the user creates a new Item record.

So as per your challenge this is your solution.
In your `class Item` declare a method for incrementing the value of counters

```
from django.db import transaction, IntegrityError  #Django inbuilt atomicity transaction block

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_num = models.IntegerField() 

    def increment_counter(self):
        temp = self #Here I have used temp so that it does not throw an out of reference error in your atomic block below
        with transaction.atomic():
            # This code executes inside a transaction.
            temp.user.counter = temp.user.counter + 1
            temp.user.save()
            temp.item_num = temp.user.counter
            temp.save()
```

In your `views.py` POST method once you saved/created the new Item you need to call the `item.increment_counter()` method

```
newly_created_item = Item.objects.create(....some data)
try:
    newly_created_item.increment_counter()
except IntegrityError:
    # Handle any exception here
```

Comment: 1. I don't see the creation of the item with the counter?  
2. Is it possible to do without transaction block, i.e single sql statement